# Nested compound views / includes / merges

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin, xamarin.android, navigation-drawer

Following XML is a test layout for my view. It shows a NavigationDrawer on the left side with a toolbar on top of the view. The toolbar shows a title and a hamburger-Icon on the top left to toggle the NavigationDrawer. Everything works fine:

My XML (I removed all height/width attributes because it's better readable):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/my_awesome_toolbar"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />
    <!-- ** MY VIEW ELEMENTS **-->
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_leftpane"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="left|start"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
        <TextView
            android:text="Test string on top of list" />
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/drawer_menulist"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@null" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

In the section `<!-- ** MY VIEW ELEMENTS **-->` I insert the view Elements for the different views (that's the only thing who changes between all views).

I have many views which need this layout above. I know about [includes](http://www.curious-creature.com/2009/02/25/android-layout-trick-2-include-to-reuse/), merges and [compound views](http://blog.trifork.com/2009/10/08/exploring-the-world-of-android-part-3/) and read many articles about these. But I am not able to create a layout for this special case and I would like to avoid copy paste the whole layout throughout all my views.

In the end I want something like this for all my views:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MyDrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
    <!-- ** MY VIEW ELEMENTS **-->
</MyDrawerLayout>
```

Is that even possible? Or is there another way to achive this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove this. This is the wrong idea:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/my_awesome_toolbar"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />
<!-- ** MY VIEW ELEMENTS **-->
</LinearLayout>
```

Just use this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/my_awesome_toolbar"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />
```

Find the View in Java, and then add views you inflate into it.

Then you can have separate XML layouts for the different Toolbar configurations you have and inflate them dynamically.
E.G.

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    orientation:horizontal>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/action_bar_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dp_fortytwo"
    android:text="@string/app_name"
    android:textColor="@color/primary_text"
    android:textSize="@dimen/dp_eighteen"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

It's convenient to keep a Singleton class for your navigation that has a reference to a ViewGroup in the Toolbar. You could inflate an "actionbar" into the Toolbar:

```
toolBar = (Toolbar) drawerLayout.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
context.setSupportActionBar(toolBar);
actionBar = (ViewGroup) LayoutInflater.from(context()).inflate(R.layout.actionbar, toolBar, false);
toolBar.addView(actionBar);
```

Then add views as needed dynamically:

```
LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.actionbar_home_icon, actionBar, true);
```

Comment: I cant remove the Toolbar-Layout (as you said) because then I am not able to find it with `drawerLayout.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);` or am I missing something?

Comment: I'm trying to say that you should *NOT* wrap the Toolbar in a LinearLayout. It seems pointless. I was trying to say you should find the Toolbar:
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id. my_awesome_toolbar);
Then inflate and add your custom layouts into that toolbar.

Comment: But I want the same toolbar in all activities. And the toolbar is in the LinearLayout because otherwise it won't show up on top of the view. Inside this LinearLayout are the other view elements depending on the different activities..

Comment: I'm telling you to use the same Toolbar, but just inflate views into it in java. That solves the problem you asked about having a lot of different layouts. So only the part of the layout the changes (the Toolbar) has a separate .xml file. You will then need to inflate these separate .xmls in Java, into the Toolbar ^^.

Comment: I didn't realize that you aren't making a native Android app. That's very relevant. Idk if my answer applies.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I would just use ***`LayoutInflater`***.

First of all I would create `FrameLayout` as a container for my layouts.
Then I would inflate required layout.
And if I would need to inflate another layout, I would just do `view_container.removeAllViews( )` and inflate that another layout.

## Everything in action

***main.xml***

```
<!-- it's not full layout, I've just taken a fragment from your example -->

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/my_awesome_toolbar"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />

    <!-- This is where you hold required layout -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/view_container"
        android:layout_width = "match_parent"
        android:layout_height = "match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

***Main.java***

```
public class Main extends AppCompatActivity
{
    @Override public void onCreate( Bundle savedInstaceBundle )
    {
        super.onCreate( );
        setContentView( R.layout.main );

        FrameLayout view_container = ( FrameLayout ) findViewById( R.id.view_container );

        /** To inflate layout **/
        LayoutInflater inflater = getApplicationContext.getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
        inflater.inflate( /*R.layout.my_layout */, view_container );

        /** To remove layout in 'view_container' **/
        view_container.removeAllViews( );

        /** To change layout in 'view_container' **/
        // 1. Remove all views
        // 2. Inflate required layout
    }
}
```

**P.S. I wrote it all in here, so I may have made some mistakes but the idea is still the same!**

Comment: So you just have one activity and just replace the content at runtime? Did I understand that right?

Comment: **Yes**. Also, I would recommend to create seperate layout files for every layout you want to inflate to `view_container` to make the project a bit more aestheticly pleasing :P

Comment: Then, could you show or explain what other activities you have ? I'll be able to help more then. **Or** if don't want to post your activities here - invite me to Skype: sw3das

Comment: We work with MvvmCross and Xamarin on a cross Plattform app. This app is already finished and works. But now we want to add the NavigationDrawer and update our UI to MaterialDesign.. Thats the reason why we have no chance to just have one activity =)

Comment: Oh, yeah... If it's possible, it's not yet something I know. Sorry then :/